# Functional plugin and task queue attempt

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, template-meta-programming

I am trying to make a proof of concept of a system where I could queue tasks to be called on context by relying essentially on types and static functions. I would like it to work like this :

```cpp
int main()
{
    PluginManager pm;
    ContextId ctxId = pm.makeContext<Plugin>(1, "un");
    pm.queueTask<Plugin>(ctxId, Plugin::execute, 2, "deux");
    pm.run();
}
```

The following code seems to almost get there, but the linked is unable to resolve the `ITask` methods to get the context id of the task and the execute the task with it's components. I believe I might be loosing the information of the actual types through the template shenanigans, but I can't figure out where.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

// Function to unroll a tuple of parameters on a function
template <typename Function, typename Params, size_t... Index>
auto dispatchParams(Function f, Params p, std::index_sequence<Index...>)
{
    return f(std::get<Index>(p)...);
}

// Function preparing index sequence to call dispatchParams
template <typename Function, typename... Params>
auto callWithTuple(Function f, tuple<Params...> args)
{
    return dispatchParams(f, args, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Params)>());
}

// Plugin identifier
enum class PluginEnum
{
    PluginA
};

// An identification object
struct ContextId
{
    PluginEnum pluginId;
    int instanceId;

    bool operator<(const ContextId& other) const
    {
        return instanceId < other.instanceId;
    }
};

// Iterface for specific context, for storage
struct IContext
{
    ContextId identity;
};

// Interface for template Task, for storage
struct ITask
{
    virtual void execute(IContext* ctx);
    virtual ContextId getContextId();
};

// Task storing what function is to be called on what context with what arguments
template <typename PLUGIN_TYPE, typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
struct Task : ITask
{
    using CONTEXT_TYPE = typename PLUGIN_TYPE::Context;
    using TUPLE = tuple<CONTEXT_TYPE*, ARGS...>;

    Task(ContextId id, FUNCTION function, ARGS... args)
        : id(id)
        , function(function)
        , argsTuple(make_tuple(nullptr, args...))
    {}

    virtual void execute(IContext* ctx)
    {
        get<0>(argsTuple) = static_cast<CONTEXT_TYPE*>(ctx);
        callWithTuple(function, argsTuple);
    }

    virtual ContextId getContextId() override { return id; }

    ContextId id;
    FUNCTION function;
    TUPLE argsTuple;
};

// The class registering the plugin context, queueing calls and executing them
struct PluginManager
{
    template <typename PLUGIN_TYPE, typename... ARGS>
    ContextId makeContext(ARGS... args)
    {
        // Define dependent type
        using CONTEXT_TYPE = typename PLUGIN_TYPE::Context;

        ContextId id{PLUGIN_TYPE::type, 123};
        CONTEXT_TYPE* ctx = new CONTEXT_TYPE(id, args...);
        _contexts[id] = static_cast<IContext*>(ctx);
        return id;
    }

    template <typename PLUGIN_TYPE, typename FUNCTION, typename... ARGS>
    void queueTask(ContextId ctxId, FUNCTION function, ARGS... args)
    {
        using TASK_TYPE = Task<PLUGIN_TYPE, FUNCTION, ARGS...>;

        TASK_TYPE* task = new TASK_TYPE(ctxId, function, args...);
        _tasks.push_back(static_cast<ITask*>(task));
    }

    void run()
    {
        while (!_tasks.empty())
        {
            ITask* task     = _tasks.front();
            IContext* ctx   = _contexts[task->getContextId()];
            task->execute(ctx);
            _tasks.pop_front();
        }
    }

    map<ContextId, IContext*> _contexts;
    deque<ITask*> _tasks;
};

// The plugin we're trying to register
struct Plugin
{
    static const PluginEnum type = PluginEnum::PluginA;

    // Definition of the plugin context / data object
    struct Context : IContext
    {
        Context(ContextId id, int number, const char* string)
            : IContext{id}
            , _dataNumber(number)
            , _dataString(string)
        {}

        const char* getString() { return _dataString; }
        int         getNumber() { return _dataNumber; }
        const char* _dataString;
        int         _dataNumber;
    };


    static void execute(Plugin::Context* context, int number, const char* string)
    {
        cout << "String is " << context->getString() << "\n";
        cout << "Number is " << context->getNumber() << "\n";
        cout << "Passed number is " << number << "\n";
        cout << "Passed string is " << string << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    PluginManager pm;
    ContextId ctxId = pm.makeContext<Plugin>(1, "un");
    pm.queueTask<Plugin>(ctxId, Plugin::execute, 2, "deux");
    pm.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ITask virtual methods are not declared abstract. This means their implementations are looked for by the linker. Just change it to:

```
virtual void execute(IContext* ctx) = 0;
virtual ContextId getContextId() = 0;
```

Comment: Oh! The kind of thing you can forget when working too late ^^! Good catch, and thank you for your reading.